# Using methods in implemented Iterator class

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I just try to create my own Iterator in a generic ArrayList class. Normally, Iterator interface includes next(), hasNext(), remove() methods. I wanted to add some extra methods. But when testing this iterator, I cant use extra methods. I can't even see them.

NOTE : MyListIterator class is an inner class in ArrayList class.

```
  private class MyListIterator implements Iterator<E>{

  private int j=0;                  

    private boolean removableNext = false;
    private boolean removablePrev= false;  

    public boolean hasNext() { return j < size; }   // size is field of outer instance

    public E next() throws NoSuchElementException {
      if (j == size) throw new NoSuchElementException("No next element");
      removableNext = true;   // this element can subsequently be removed
      removablePrev=false;
      return data[j++];   // post-increment j, so it is ready for future call to next
    }   

    public boolean hasPrevious(){
        return (j > -1) ;
    }

    public E previous(){

        if(j==-1) throw new NoSuchElementException("No previous element");
        removablePrev= true;
        removableNext=false;
        return data[j--];   
    }

    public void remove(){
        if (!removableNext && !removablePrev) throw new IllegalStateException("nothing to remove");

        if(removableNext){
        ArrayList.this.remove(j-1);  
        j--;                         
        removableNext = false;
        }

        if(removablePrev){
        ArrayList.this.remove(j+1);  
        j++;                         
        removablePrev = false;
        }
    }

    public void set(E e){
        if (!removableNext && !removablePrev) throw new IllegalStateException("nothing to remove");

        if(removableNext){
        ArrayList.this.set(j-1,e);  
        j--;                         
        removableNext = false;
        }       

        if(removablePrev){
        ArrayList.this.set(j+1,e);  
        j++;                         
        removablePrev = false;
        }       
    }       
 }
```

When testing I just see remove(), next(), hasNext() methods which are implemented from Iterator.

Test class is :

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DriverIterator {

  public static void main(String[]args){

     ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

     list.add(0, 1);
     list.add(0, 2);
     list.add(0, 3);
     list.add(0, 4);
     list.add(0, 5);

     System.out.println(list.toString());

     Iterator<Integer> iter = list.myListIterator();
  }
}
```

The ArrayList class is belongs to me, if necessary I can share it too.

Comment: Well your `iter` variable is of type `Iterator<Integer>`, so yes, you'll only be able to us methods declared in that. If you change the type of `iter` to `MyListIterator<Integer>` then you'll be able to use the extra methods. (I'd also strongly advise against creating your own class with a name that's already used in `java.util`... it's a recipe for confusion.)

Comment: But i cant do MyListIterator<Integer> because its an private inner class. In ArrayList class.

Comment: Please share ArrayList class as well. But as @Jon  Skeet said you need to work with MyListIterator. To do this you need to make  MyListIterator class public and have myListIterator method to return MyListIterator type.

Comment: So make it a public class. How do you expect to be able to refer to methods the compiler effectively can't "see"?

Comment: yes i got it . I made it public and define my object like this:  `ArrayList.MyListIterator iter = (ArrayList.MyListIterator) list.myListIterator();`  and finally i can see my methods.